# Introspection endpoint with django oauth toolkit

Tags: python, django, oauth, django-oauth

Django OAuth toolkit recently added ability to separate the provider and resource servers using Introspection endpoint. However, the documentation is not clear on how to properly achieve this. Anyone who has successfully done this?